# Issue while migrating JBPM 7.31.0 with Sybase DB, rest API not found

Tags: java, jboss, drools, jbpm, kie-server

I'm using JBPM 7.31.0 with oracle DB, and everything is working fine. 
But now when switching to Sybase DB, and calling some of rest APIs(ex: process definitions) to result in '404 Not found' response.

After checking the server log I found

> Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: RESTEASY003210:
>   Could not find resource for full path:
>   http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/queries/processes/definitions

note that the same is working fine with oracle DB.

Server log URL [log file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kQDVXJB7Rk65D3c7gek98vmTAKDkrFDD?usp=sharing).

Note that, I tried the same on the latest jbpm-installer(7.33.0) and the same issue occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more debugging, I found that the real cause of the error was

`ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) Incorrect syntax near 'cross'`.

Now when I changed the dialect from 'org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect' to 'org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseASE15Dialect' the issue was solved since cross joins are not supported by SybaseDialect.